# Display Sale icon on special price products in magento. Only at homepage it is showing not in all pages

Tags: magento-1.7, product, product-list, php-5.4

> Display Sale icon on special price products in magento. Only at homepage it is showing not in all pages.
>
> Code I have edited in
> app/design/frontend/default/template/catalog/product/list.html
>
> from the line number: 95

```
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
<?php 
    // Get the Special Price
    $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice(); 
    // Get the Special Price FROM date
    $specialPriceFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialFromDate();
    // Get the Special Price TO date
    $specialPriceToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialToDate();
    // Get Current date
    $today =  time();
 
    if ($specialprice):
        if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
 ?>
    <img src="../images/sale-icon.png" width="101" height="58" class="onsaleicon" />
<?php  
        endif;
    endif;
?>     
</a>
```

This icon is displaying in homepage only not in All product list of pages. How do i display in all pages?

Comment: Do you mean all product list pages or just any page with a product?

Answer (score 4):

This could be the problem:

```
<img src="../images/sale-icon.png" width="101" height="58" class="onsaleicon" />
```

When you are not on homepage the relative path to the image is wrong.
Use this instead:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/sale-icon.png')?>" width="101" height="58" class="onsaleicon" />
```

and place your image in `skin/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/images/`.

*Small tip:*
Don't use this:

```
$specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice(); 
    // Get the Special Price FROM date
    $specialPriceFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialFromDate();
    // Get the Special Price TO date
    $specialPriceToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialToDate();
```

You are loading the product 3 times and you don't need to do that.  You can load it only once if neccesary:

```
$mainProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$specialprice = $mainProduct->getSpecialPrice(); 
// Get the Special Price FROM date
$specialPriceFromDate = $mainProduct->getSpecialFromDate();
// Get the Special Price TO date
$specialPriceToDate = $mainProduct->getSpecialToDate();
```

but you can go without loading it, by editing the attributes `'special_price', 'special_from_date' and`special_to_date`` ` and setting ``used in product listing`to`yes`.

*bigger tip:*

You can check if the product has a discount without checking the special price and the dates. This works even if you have a discount from a catalog rule:

```
if ($_product->getPrice() > $_product->getFinalPrice())
```